# How to assign the same value in B row when the cells in A row have the same value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns and multiple rows. In the first column, the cells may have the same value, however the 3rd column has different values! how can I write a function  in such way so the second column gets the same value, for the duplicate cells in first column?

```
 1. Chris Developer Project A
 2. Nick  _________ Project A
 3. Chris _________ Project B
 4. Nick  Intern    Project A
 5. Chris _________ Project C
```

Comment: Where do you want to write formula? Column 2 already have data.

Comment: Include your wanted result

Comment: Where do the values "Developer" and "Intern" (and so on...?) come from (which cells are referenced to pull those values)?

Comment: I have a way bigger database with duplicate names in the first column. so I am looking for an iteration  looking like this: 
    for i=1 to length.A
         for j=i+1 to length.A 
             if  A[i] = A[j] then
                 B[i] = B[j]
I hope that makes sence to you

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFS`. Place in `B1` and drag down.

```
=IFS(A1="Chris","Developer",A1="Nick","Intern")
```

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45